# Array of Structs cannot read intergers assigned to them c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am trying to assign values to the Arrival, BurstTime, and IOTime arrays. It worked fine when I didn't have Arrival[9]. However trying to pass multiple ints into the variable doesn't work. I get -86638*** numbers. I have been trying to find an answer for days, No luck.

This is my struct.

```
struct ReadyQueue
{
    //static const int MAX_NUMBER = 10;
    int ArrivalTime[10];
    int  BurstTime[10];
    int IOTime[10];
    std::string Name;

};
```

and my variables

```
P[0].ArrivalTime[10] =       0, 98, 221, 327, 423, 530, 628, 719, 788 ;
P[1].ArrivalTime[8]         = 17, 116, 208, 320, 437, 554, 665, 754 ;               // P2
P[2].ArrivalTime[7]         = 27, 125, 238, 364, 468, 579, 680;                     // P3
P[3].ArrivalTime[8]         = 45, 155, 276, 392, 515, 642, 739, 820 ;               // P4
P[4].ArrivalTime[10]        = 62, 186, 343, 489, 603, 715, 807, 887, 952, 997;      // P5
P[5].ArrivalTime[7]         = 67, 174, 262, 348, 446, 566, 654;                     // P6
P[6].ArrivalTime[9]         = 77, 148, 216, 302, 359, 461, 546, 622, 697;           // P7
P[7].ArrivalTime[8]         = 83, 196, 306, 409, 499, 608, 702, 773 ;               // P8
P[8].ArrivalTime[9]         = 92, 192, 296, 386, 492, 599, 692, 734, 803;           // P9


P[0].BurstTime[8]           = 17 , 18, 17, 16, 14, 16, 14, 15, 15;
P[0].IOTime[8]              = 24, 73, 31, 27, 33, 43, 64, 19 ;

P[1].BurstTime[8]           = 10, 9, 8, 7, 9, 12, 15, 19 ;
P[1].IOTime[7]              = 31, 35, 42, 43, 47, 43, 51 ;

P[2].IOTime[6]              = 51, 53, 61, 31, 43, 31 ;
P[2].BurstTime[7]           = 18, 23, 24, 22, 21, 20, 12 ;

P[3].BurstTime[8]           = 17, 19, 20, 17, 15, 12, 15, 14 ;
P[3].IOTime[7]              = 42, 55, 54, 52, 67, 72, 66 ;

P[4].BurstTime[10]          = 5, 6, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5 ;
P[4].IOTime[9]              = 61, 82, 71, 61, 62, 51, 77, 61, 42 ;

P[5].BurstTime[7]           = 10, 12, 14, 11, 15, 13, 11 ;
P[5].IOTime[6]              = 35, 41, 33, 32, 41, 29 ;

P[6].BurstTime[7]           = 6, 7, 5, 4, 5, 7, 8, 6, 5 ;
P[6].IOTime[8]              = 18, 21, 19, 16, 29, 21, 22, 24 ;

P[7].BurstTime[8]           = 9, 12, 14, 14, 16, 14, 13, 15 ;
P[7].IOTime[7]              = 52, 42, 31, 21, 43, 31, 32 ;

P[8].BurstTime[9]           = 6, 4, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 4 ;
P[8].BurstTime[8]           = 35, 41, 33, 32, 41, 29, 16, 22 ;
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Since you are using `std::string`, I assume this is C++, not C. Is there a reason you are not using `std::vector`? What about using a `class` instead of `struct`?

Comment: by the way since the array length is not fixed, I would suggest using pointers instead of arrays, and using a variable for saving the length since there is no other way you can find out the array length in c and c++ (exept maybe putting a wrong value like a negative value if all the values must be positive to determine that the array is finished before arriving to the tenth element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to clarify what those assignments do, because I see some wrong answers.
Let's see it with an example:

```
P[0].ArrivalTime[10] =       0, 98, 221, 327, 423, 530, 628, 719, 788 ;
```

First, that statement is assigning `0` in the `eleventh` element of the ArrivalTime array and I don't think you wanted to do this due to ArrivalTime[9] is the last element.

Second, the comma operator evaluates the first operand, discard the result, and then evaluates the second operand and returns his value. In the example you could think this evaluation returns `788`, but `assign` operator have more precedence than `comma`, so, the statement will evaluate like this:

```
((P[0].ArrivalTime[10] =       0), 98, 221, 327, 423, 530, 628, 719, 788 ;
```

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I need to do more reading. This sounds like common programming sense. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note that my answer contained a mistake which I corrected it: equal operator has a higher priority than the comma operator (it might still contain traces of it)**

This is not how you assign an array to a variable.
what you are doing is simply:
assign <strike>788</strike> **0** to `p[0].ArrivalTime[10] //the 11th element of p[0]` which is outside the reserved space for the array
because the comma operator what it does is that it evaluates every one from left to right and return the last value: example:

```
int i=0,j;
j=i++,(i+=5),i;    //j=0 and i=6 //because it is in fact (j=i++),(i+=5),i;
j=(i++,(i+=5),i);    //j=6 and i=6
```

what you are trying to do is assign `p[0].arrivalTime` to an array of 10. You should do it this way:

```
P[0].ArrivalTime[0] = 0 ;
P[0].ArrivalTime[1] = 98 ;
...
P[0].ArrivalTime[9] = 788 ;
```

I don't know any method that assign an array to an array variable after declaration

Comment: @Cheersandhth (the editor) that what I meant but I don't know my left from my right all the time, thanks for the edit :)

Comment: As I say in my answer, be careful in the precedence of operators. Example: p[0].ArrivalTime[10] will be assigned 0

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
struct ReadyQueue
{
    //static const int MAX_NUMBER = 10;
    int ArrivalTime[10];
    int  BurstTime[10];
    int IOTime[10];
    std::string Name;

};
```

to this:

```
struct Item
{
    int ArrivalTime;
    int  BurstTime;
    int IOTime;
};

struct Ready_queue
{
    string name;
    queue<Item> items;
};
```

where `queue` is `std::queue`.

If that doesn't suit your higher level purpose, then something similar that does suit that (unexplained) purpose.

The main point is an inversion of the logical structure, putting related data together.

---

Do note that e.g. `x = 6, 4, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 4 ;` is parsed as `(x = 6), 4, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 4 ;` and thus is equivalent to just `= 6;`. The longwinded expression after the assignment is using the **comma operator**, which evaluates the expressions in ordinary reading order, producing the value of the last one. Due to the parsing also that final value is discarded.

Comment: Due to precedence, in fact `= 6, 4, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 4 ` is equal to `= 6`. Not the same if you'd have `= (6, 4, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 5, 4 )`.

Comment: @jaba10: Thanks, you're right. I was thinking about initialization, since that's what the code *should* have been.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do assignments to arrays like this in c/c++.  You can use a similar syntax with {} for initializing arrays, but it won't work for what you want to do here.  You could use memcpy to copy the arrays into the memory locations in the struct.

```
memcpy( p[0].ArrivalTime,
    (const int[9]) {0, 98, 221, 327, 423, 530, 628, 719, 788},
    sizeof(int [9])
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the comma is an operator which evaluates a list of expressions and returns the value of the last expression. This means that

```
P[0].ArrivalTime[10] =       0, 98, 221, 327, 423, 530, 628, 719, 788 ;
```

assigns `0` to the value at index 10 of the array named `ArrivalTime` and ignores the rest of the list.

Comment: Hi, would you take a look at my answer please? You're not giving attention to the precedence of operators __assign__ and __comma__.

Comment: @jaba10 You are exactly right! Thanks for the catch.